# Getting data with RxJava and retrofit

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am using RxJava with retrofit to get data from an API then filtering the data with a `for` loop in the `onNext` Method.  Is there any way not to use the `for` loop and just use RxJava to filter or improve the code?

```
 _subscriptions.add(
                jamSpeakServiceApi.getAllWords()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Observer<List<WordApi>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {
                                Log.d("retroffit Completed", "Completed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                Log.d("retroffit error", e.toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(List<WordApi> wordApis) {
                                /*Observable.from(wordApis)
                                        .filter(s -> Word.getWordFormDatabase(s.getWord()) != null)
                                        .filter(s -> s.getCountry().toLowerCase().equals("jamaica"))
                                        .filter(s -> Word.getWordLikeFormDatabase(s.getWord()) != null)
                                        .subscribe();*/

                                for (WordApi x: wordApis){
                                    if(x.getCountry().toLowerCase().equals("jamaica")== true){
                                        Word.saveWordFromApi(x);
                                        Log.d(x.getWord(),x.getWord());
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        })
        );
```

Comment: Take a look at this blog http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/ it's quite long, but you can find here what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `flat` to emit each `wordApi` and then you will be able to filter your data and apply your function one by one.

Your stream should look like this:

```
jamSpeakServiceApi.getAllWords()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(wordApis -> Observable.from(wordApis))
            .filter(wordApi -> wordApi.getCountry().toLowerCase().equals("jamaica"))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<WordApi>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("retroffit Completed", "Completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("retroffit error", e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(WordApi wordApi) {
                    Word.saveWordFromApi(wordApi);
                    Log.d(wordApi.getWord(),wordApi.getWord());
                }
            })
```

I used some lambdas, and I recommend you to use them too. Take a look at the Retrolambda Gradle plugin. It works well with an Android environment.